# How to enable hugepages on Travis CI build

Tags: travis-ci, huge-pages

I tried following config lines and got [`Permission denied`](https://travis-ci.org/plokhotnyuk/actors/jobs/46807215#L110)

```
install:
 - sudo echo 2000 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Travis VM you can set up hugepages using `sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=<Number of pages>`.

The maximum number of pages that can be allocated is 512. For an example of using huge pages in Travis, see [this .travis.yml](https://github.com/NetSys/bess/blob/3b2bd708459f916e41c9649b5731da2d4999581e/.travis.yml#L44).